# RESTful API complex queries

Tags: mysql, json, api, rest

I have a simple restful api for destinations. It's built using Express and sequelize with a MySQL database.
It has Cities, Countries and Regions. Cities belongTo Countries which belongsTo Regions.

Now, it's usual that I have to do complex find operations. For example:

GET /cities

```
{
  where: {
    name: {'$like': 'bue%'}
  },
  include: [{model: Country, where: {region_id: 1}}]
}
```

With this I am trying to fetch all cities where the name starts with 'bue', but only whose country's region_id is 1.
This could be taken one step forward if I specify which fields I want returned. The models have some text fields which I might not need, so the above query becomes:

```
{
  where: {
    name: {'$like': 'bue%'}
  },
  attributes: ['id', 'name'],
  include: [{
    model: Country, 
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    where: {region_id: 1}
  }]
}
```

This is already quite complex. Image if I want to include the Country's region and add some filter there as well.

So, my question is: how do I go about passing this complex query?
Right now I am using url params with encoded json. So I have something like:

```
where: {name: {'$like': 'bue%'}} => Becomes:

/cities?where=%7Bname%3A%20%7B%27%24like%27%3A%20%27bue%25%27%7D%7D
```

You can see that this results in a damn ugly URL that is quite hard to work with. If my query is complex, the URL becomes a monster. If my `where` param as OR / AND and complex conditions, it gets really big and messy.

Anyway, that's the question. Should I keep things as they are. Is there any more proper way to do this somehow.
Some example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One sort of "standard" solution is to POST the complex query (with the query in the HTTP body), let the server store it somewhere and return a new URL that references the stored query. After that clients can issue a GET on the new query URL to get the result.

Comment: That looks more far fetched than simply sending the encoded json in the query params.